# C# OleDb Connection to mdb File with changed character set to UTF8

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

i have a problem to change Character set to UTF8 when i ma connecting to my mdb file.
I can connect to this, the only problem is it has some š,ž,č etc. characters in it. So i wanted to change character set in my connectionString to UTF8.

My connectionString looks like this:

```
string conectionString = "Provider=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;";
```

This connection string will connect me just fine. But when i add this:

```
string conectionString = "Provider=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Extended properties='Character set=UTF8;'";
```

it will throw an error : Could not find installable isam. I was trying to find more about it but only thig that i found was about single quotes.
I know there is a lot of questions about this but I go through a lot of them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The property name should be `CharacterSet`, with proper casing and no space inbetween, and IIRC the codepage number for UTF8 is 65001, maybe try that; and I'm also not sure about the single quotes, where did you look that up?

Comment: @dlatikay I was trying the 65001 too and same result. And yes my bad about quotes. They shoud be used if there more then one extended properties. if there is one there are no need for them. But even with or without them it is not working.

Comment: @dlatikay its a pity i forgot my notbook at work :( i will try it tomorrow and let you know how it turned. but i think i already tried it. If any other solution strikes you i will be happy to hear it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @dlatikay So CharacterSet=65001 isnt working too.

Comment: Is this a typo: `Provider=Provider=Microsoft.Jet...`? and have you tried `properties` with a capital `P`?

Comment: Try keeping the quotes as there might be some confusion with the first `=`, i.e. `Extended Properties=`. So, `Extended Properties=\"CharacterSet=UTF8;\""`. The last quote just ends the connection string. (Not tested.) [p.s., i've only found examples with excel. is this possible w access?]

Comment: Are the accented characters in the name of the mdb file?

Comment: @wazz Hi, i already make this work for me. I created a method for Decoding string from Windows-1250 to UTF-8 cause i wasn't able to move forward with character set. I tried all your advice before and didn't work so i think it is not possible to use character set with access just for now.  But thanks for all comments

Comment: ok. i found this if anyone needs it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f9e5094-0c29-42da-bb6f-059c0270cb95/exception-thrown-by-oledbconnectionopen-while-connecting-to-mdb-file-that-has-foreign-characters?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Answer (score 0):

I Know that this is too late, but for the people that want to know the answer.
I'm using some more for the Extend Properties, I rescue it from ChatGPT but I add the knowledge that I got.
For your location, has to be the folder that contains your file, after you can do a query like "SELECT * FROM [/*Name of your file with extention*/]"
The correct format to the connection would be `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=/*Your location*/;Extend Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'CharacterSet=65001'"`

In your string variable, you can use:

```
string connectionString= $@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={/*Your location*/};Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'CharacterSet=65001'""";
```

I'm using the template string and the @ for get the scape of '"'